# Qt application will not start on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, windows-7, qt-creator

I wrote a Qt application on Linux that compiles and runs. When I try to compile the code on `Qt Creator` on Windows I can't run the executable.

The application will only run from within Qt Creator. Does this have something to do with dependencies? I know for static builds, I need to build a static version of Qt Creator. But aside from doing that, what else would I need to do for the program to run?

Answer (score 1):

You can place the required QT dlls, QtCore, QtGui, etc, in your .exe's folder.

You should be able to find these dll's in your QT install folder.

If you're not sure which dll's you need - you may want to try out [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

Comment: Wow, there are a lot of dependencies. Guess I should either create an installer or just build a static version of Qt Creator.

Comment: It's best to create an installer with the QT dlls as well as the Visual C++ redistributable. In my case, the installer is fairly small, at around 10-15MB.

Answer (score 0):

You should place Qt DLLs along the release version of your executable. These are Qt5Core.dll, Qt5Gui.dll and possibly the ones for other modules that you have used. These dll files are in your installed Qt Directory in bin folder. You should also place msvcr100.dll and msvcp100.dll in case you are using MSVS2010. If you are using plugins you should place their dll in a folder named "plugins" beside your exe. In case of using icons and images you should ship their dlls like qico.dll and qsvg.dll in a folder named "imageformats".